# Is it correct to say "that place is like 5 miles from here"?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, filler-words

Is it correct to say "that place is like 5 miles from here"? I'm not sure if the use of "like" is correct?

Comment: Hello jorge, you might be interestd in joining with our new proposal [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions). This kind of questions might be considered too basic here. Please, try now!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this sentence it is informal or slang and means "about" or "approximately".
e.g. "How far is it to McDonald's?" "It's like 5 miles"

In the right context, it could also imply a "presumed magnitude", as Fortiter put it.
e.g. "Can you give me a ride to John's house?"  "Dude, that's like 20 miles away."

Comment: In "youth speak" this use of like probably indicates the presumed magnitude of the distance rather than any uncertainty. It asserts that it is unreasonable to expect him to travel that distance for such a trivial purpose as getting a job (for example).

Comment: It would depend on context and tone of voice. But you are right, it could definitely mean that.  Added to answer

Comment: I disagree. 'Like' here is still just a filler. Just because it is in a location that is often used to put an 'uncertainty' qualifier, doesn't mean it is.

Comment: @Mitch maybe it's a regional thing, but it is certainly used both ways were I come from. In "Regina is, like, ridiculously hot."  like=filler.  In "It's like five miles from here." like=approximately. "A marathon is, like, 26.2 miles." like=filler.

Answer (score 2):

"Like" is a placeholder introduced in recent developments in English, usually adopted by younger users. If you are to replace it with anything, use "er" or "um" or some similar interjection.

Comment: I think the OP's use of "like" could be a replacement for "about" or "approximately" as Kevin answered.  The filler "like" would be used this way, "That concert was like totally awesome, man!" (IMO, of course!) :-)

Comment: @Kristina, you are a competent speaker of English language and we need you on English Language Learners. Have you thought to join up there? Please, take a look, thank you.

Comment: @Carlo_R., thanks for the compliment and for the reminder - I meant to join ELL - I'll do it right now! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would say no. I think "like" needs a noun as its object. You could maybe say it is something like a 5-mile distance from here. To use "like" with an adjectival phrase sounds too much like informal spoken English.

Comment: So, like, what's wrong with informal spoken English?

Comment: We like precision.